# WebConfigurationManager error after adding siteMap

Tags: asp.net, configuration, sitemap, web-config, webconfigurationmanager

I'm getting this error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'Configuration' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");

This code has been in place for 5+ months without this issues, only today after adding this sitemap code do I have this issue.

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="ExtendedSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="ExtendedSiteMapProvider" type="Configuration.ExtendedSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
            </providers>
        </siteMap>
```

I tried adding "System.Web." before the "Configuration ", but that did not work either:

```
System.Web.Configuration myWebConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
```

Error   1   'System.Web.Configuration' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Configuration.Configuration instead of System.Web.Configuration

```
        // Get the configuration object for a Web application
        // running on the local server. 
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/~") 
            as System.Configuration.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're being given is correct, System.Web.Configuration is a namespace and not a type and so can not be instantiated.

You want to use the type System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager if my memory serves me correctly.

EDIT: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx)